# how to block multiple query in 1 time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm using php+PDO+mysql to `SELECT` users, to complete my page I have to get rid of 1 security issue. on each query from server-side I have "`SELECT id,first_name,last_name FROM users WHERE $conditions`" and the rest is from client side `$_POST["conditions"]` (the filter) now how can I make sure they don't inject another UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT/SELECT... at the end???

or if you think I'm just doing it all wrong, please tell me, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of $conditions?

Comment: It's really undesirable to have users fully modify the conditions. What for example someone searches for `login_name LIKE 'a%'` and narrows it down in multiple searches to the full login-name? (next step: password). Have an array with `$searchableColumns`, checkboxes for all of them and on post `foreach($serchableColumns as $c) { if (checkbox checked) { add '$c LIKE ?' to the query } }`

Comment: example $conditions 'first_name LIKE %blahblah%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and safest approach is to avoid building a query injecting clauses posted from the client.

You should add a "layer" of separation/abstraction between $_POST["conditions"] and $conditions.

Let the client ask what data have to be fetched with a convention you'll decide.

For example $_POST["conditions"] may be empty for "all the users". If $_POST["conditions"] contains a number then the user with matching ID is fetched... That's just a basic example to give the idea, of course.

Then you parse $_POST["conditions"] and build up $conditions accordingly.

As your server-side code builds up $conditions you can then safely inject it in your query.

If you have to take some value (the ID taking the example above) and insert into the query use a *prepared statement* to do so.

Note that you may find convenient to use more POST variables instead of a single one for defining what user(s) have to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You should know exactly what kind of statements are allowed and act accordingly. For example, let's say that you want to be able to execute 3 different queries depending on the user input:

```
'id LIKE %param%'
'first_name LIKE %param%'
'last_name LIKE %param%'
```

You don't want to insert these directly. Instead, you make 2 different POST variables:
`$_POST['field']` will select the field and `$_POST['param']` will be your search parameter.

A very basic example:

```
//you can just store all these in array if there are many
//we don't use POST directly, we set a variable depending on it's value
$field="";
if ($_POST['field']=="id") $field="id";
elseif ($_POST['field']=="first_name") $field="first_name";
elseif ($_POST['field']=="last_name") $field="last_name";

if ($field!="") {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE ".$field." LIKE :param");
    $sql->bindParam("param", "%".$_POST['param']."%");
    $sql->execute();  
}
else echo "Error!";
```

Never trust the user input.